# Testing predictive power of a set of features

Tags: regression, correlation, predictive-models, feature-selection, bioinformatics

This is perhaps a typical setup in Bioinformatics: we need to build a model to predict a dependent biological variable (say $y$), given a large set of (usually genomic) features $X$ (which might not all be relevant). The size of the training set, $n$,  is usually much smaller than the number of (potential) features, $|X|$. The trick is then to find the right set of features which most likely be the most predictive of the response variable $y$. Now, suppose using some prior biological knowledge and pre-processing, I have selected a subset of $X$, say $X'$ that is deemed to be the more relevant features to predict $y$ (note that: in this case, we still have $|X'|>n$). I want to know **how predictive** it is against $y$ in the training set. Of course, I can select a certain statistical/machine learning method, say stepwise regression or LASSO (or any other regression method that can handle $|X'|> n$), and then do cross-validation within the training set to get an idea of how predictive $X'$ is towards $y$. However, I was wondering whether I can do this in a non-model-specific way, i.e., a *general* metric to say how predictive $X'$ is for **any** model. I don't think simple correlation really captures what I need, since there can be many high-correlating variables which might not really be good predictors (spurious correlation).

Comment: There is an excellent and recent CV discussion of this specific issue including commentary by Frank Harrell, chair of Biostatistics at Vanderbilt here ... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179693/understanding-how-good-a-prediction-is-in-logistic-regression/179697#179697

Answer (score 2):

I can direct you to the [Fast Feature Selection](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233882725_A_fast_feature_selection_method_for_high-dimensional_MEG_BCI_data) based on R^2-values, based on Pearson Correlation Coefficient. This method was introduced for multidimensional MEG or EEG data, however it suits any **binary** machine learning problem. Put simply: it computes correlations of data and labels, then sorts obtained values, finally only the best scoring features are selected.

I implemented the approach for MATLAB and LIBSVM found at [github](https://github.com/dthettich/BSClassify). In my implementation you can define the amount of features to be selected, e.g. 100, 1000 or everything above the mean of scoring values.

Comment: Hi @dthettich, thanks for the suggestion. Can you comment on the applicability of this method for regression problems?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, the method in its present form requires two discrete labels. Yet maybe there is a possibility for you to extract meaningful features by "Mutual Information".

Answer (score 1):

Accurately determining the predictive power of a set of features with respect to a dependent variable is a tricky problem, and there is no universal metric which can tell you exactly that.

You already selected a group of features $X'$ that you want to use, but it is in general common to use a feature selection method to determine such a set. Since you already have $X'$ you can instead use some of the metrics of these feature selection methods to determine the usefulness of your features in terms of prediction.

I personally prefer Correlation-based Feature Subset Selection which evaluates a set of features based on its correlation with respect to the depend variable, and the inter-correlation (i.e. redundancy) between individual features in the set:

http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~mhall/thesis.pdf

Other metrics that may be useful are the information gain, or gain-ratio (commonly used in decision trees) to determine the entropy of the data after splitting the data with respect to a feature