# Follow up question to: Why does logistic regression generate well-calibrated models?

Tags: regression, logistic, calibration

I've read all answers and comments here: [Why does logistic regression produce well-calibrated models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208867/why-does-logistic-regression-produce-well-calibrated-models)
but still not clear about the answer.

Can someone please elaborate why the following equation means model is well calibrated?

[image: setting derivative of loss function to zero]

The two sides of above equation are sum of products. I don't quite understand why we can take [image] off the equation and have

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please edit your question (specifically the title) to make it clear how this question differs from the linked question. Follow-up questions are fine, but now your title is identical to the original question, which attracts close votes.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It's a follow up question to the linked one, but I don't know how to tag it to make it sounds like a follow up question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation applies to every column $x_j$ of the design matrix. In particular, it applies to the first column $x_0$, which is a vector of all ones. That's why the $x$'s drop out in the second equation.

Comment: Ah I see! I forgot there is a column of all 1s for the intercept. Thank you so much!