# Calibration-in-the-small and logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, calibration

It is well agreed ([for example this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208867/why-does-logistic-regression-produce-well-calibrated-models) ) that Logistic Regression guarantees that model will produce well calibrated in the large (mean) predictions.

Does Logistic Regression guarantees that  calibration-in-the-small is good too, or not necessarily?

If calibration-in-the-small is not guaranteed to be good (or in case when it is not good), what is known about the reasons?

Are there known methods to improve calibration-in-the-small via some modified loss function (or some other ways) while training LR model, or this is only solved by using some calibration function/transformation that is applied on outputs from prediction?

Comment: Could you direct us to the actual quotation?  I can locate the [comment about calibration-in-the-small and "calibration-in-the-tiny,"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208867/why-does-logistic-regression-produce-well-calibrated-models#comment682177_208872) but I am unable to find any comment that agrees with your initial statement.

Comment: Whuber, edited orginal question with details

Comment: You still seem to be reading something into Frank Harrell's comment that isn't there.  The word "only" does not appear.

Comment: @whuber

Frank wrote: "This addresses only calibration-in-the-large which is not what we want: calibration-in-the-small. – Frank Harrell Aug 20 '18 at 12:35"


Let me ask different way : does logistic regression guarantee calibration-in-the-small?
My experience is (on range of model types  trained/fitted to very large amounts of data) - we get almost perfect  calibration in the large, and ALWAYS severe lack of calibration in the small.

So I am trying to understand if we have explanation why in-the-small happens to be not calibrated and what are common techniques to solve this

Comment: Prof. Harrell was referring to the *answer* under which his first comment appeared.  That comment was not making a statement about logistic regression in general.  I agree that you have a legitimate and interesting question here (which is why I did not vote to close it), but would prefer that it not be based on a possible mischaracterization of other work.

Comment: @Whuber thank you for clarifying - I corrected question to avoid mischaracterization (sorry for that) and genuinely interested in hearing advice about this problem.