What does calibration mean when the outcome is not categorical?
In a situation where a binary variable is of interest and we want to predict the probability of either event (dog vs cat, say), it is common to talk about the calibration of the predictions, if the predicted probability values align with the reality of event occurrence. After all, if we keep predicting events to happen with probability $0.9$, only for the event to happen is $60\%$ of situations, our predictions are disputed by reality.
In a situation where three or more categories are in play (dog vs cat vs horse, say), we can apply similar logic. If we keep predicting a dog with probability $0.9$, only for the outcome to be a dog in $60\%$ of those situations, our predictions are disputed by reality.
That is for a categorical outcome. What is the generalization or analogue when the outcome is not categorical but continuous? How do we assess calibration and miscalibration Continuous random variables have zero probability for all values.

Potentially related here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163414/what-is-calibration

I'm not sure the literature is widely using "calibration" to refer to prediction of continuous outcomes. By all means link some noteworthy examples if I'm mistaken. Calibration and discrimination for predictions of a 0/1 event most closely resemble the bias and precision of continuous predictions, but for some reason most reviewers find it copasetic to just report them together as the MSE.

@AdamO: you may find my answer interesting. (Unfortunately, I won't be able to reply to comments within the next week because I'm on the road and should really not be reading & posting here...)

There is no analogue necessary. The concept of calibration is equally valid for continuous outcomes. Tilmann Gneiting discussed all this in a number of papers in the past, e.g., Gneiting, Balabdaoui & Raftery (2007) or Gneiting & Raftery (2007) or Gneiting & Katzfuss (2014). His positions have been quite well accepted in the forecasting community.

Could you please add the most important part of the intuition? Does calibration of a probability model mean something like unbiasedness of the probability estimator? Would this mean that unbiasedness measures something like calibration? Or is there fundamentally more to say (intuitionwise)?

For probabilistic regression models (which e.g. try to estimate location and scale parameters), I can imagine how we could argue that calibration can be defined through coverage of a prediction interval. But how is it with regression models which just minimize mse, i.e. estimate the conditional mean... And isn't coverage in the case of probabilistic regression models also (in a sloppy sense) about getting the location and scale parameters right, i.e. be unbiased (more or less)

Thank you for the citations. I have been going through Gneiting’s Series B article. However, saying calibration is exactly the same for continuous outcomes as categorical seems to take it too far. With categorical outcomes, we check if predicted probabilities align with actual outcomes: if predicting probabilities above 90% aligns with about 90-95% event occurrence (probably good calibration) or more like 60-70% event occurrence (rather poor calibration). With a continuous outcome, we can’t do that. (Or can we? But how?)

@Dave One-dimensional distributions can be characterized by the exceedence probabilities $Y \le x$ for all $x$. This is one idea to approach the assessment.

I absolutely agree with the answer by Stephan Kolassa and want to add a less theoretical perspective: A forecast is calibrated when it is reliable, i.e. we can rely on the outcome to have (approximately) the statistical property specified by the forecast. This property might be anything, a number, an interval, a pdf, you name it.
Put loosely, calibration asks: In the cases where the forecast predicts X, does the outcome have the property X? Now you can put almost anything for X:

In cases where the probability forecast predicts the event to happen with probability 0.9, does the event happen with probability 0.9 ?
In cases where the mean forecasts predicts 3, is the mean of the outcome 3 ?
In cases where the probabilistic forecast predicts $F$, does the outcome follow the distribution $F$?

